# gson parsing multiple objects inside a object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

So i have a json response as following:

I am trying to parse the following json response from an api. But it has a structure i do not have control over.

```
{
"news3962": {},
"news3961": {},
"news3960": {},
"news3959": {},
"news3958": {},
"news3951": {},
"news3950": {},
"news3948": {},
"news3943": {},
"news3947": {}
}
```

All the news items contain the same structure. How will i parse this response so that i return an array containing NewsItems?

Normally the response should be an array with anonoymous objects but this is not the case

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Jackson I would catch this as a Map<String, News> and then get the array via Map.values().toArray(new News[0]). Alas, this is not Jackson, I have no idea if this will work with Gson, and this is not an answer. just a comment.

Comment: Try to parse the given JSON to Map and then take the valueSet.

Comment: This is not valid JSON; are object member keys really defined as is, that is `newsXXXX` and not `"newsXXXX"` as it should be?

Comment: I am sorry you are right. @fge it does contain quotes.

Comment: Maybe you could solve this problem if Gson has the equivalent of `@JsonAnySetter` for Jackson; this way you could just ignore the key and inject the values in a collection

Comment: @fge: yes it is. the custom gson deserializer suggested by Jonik  does exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: thanks for the help guys. I found the solution to my problem see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lez Kuznetsov.

I am trying to parse the response to a HashMap object. After that i take the retrieved hashmap.values().